# Cargo copying of Config files not working

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat7, cargo, maven-cargo

So, what I am trying to do is to automate my JMeter testing process, and for this I use Cargo to deploy to a Tomcat container and run the JMeter scripts there and am using a pom based on what is described in:- http://www.alexecollins.com/content/jmeter-integration-test-template-pom/
After, a lot of effort I got it working.

But, now of course for testing I want to use a testdb instead of my actual db and for this i need a custom context.xml (instead of my production context.xml with which everything works) where using jndi i am defining jdbc parameters.

So, I was planning on having a testcontext.xml which I have cargo copy into the container while running JMeter tests using something like the copy configfile option of cargo - http://cargo.codehaus.org/Custom+File+Configurations.
But it doesn't seem to be working. And I have been debugging for hours and can't figure it out.

I am pasting my pom file of a test-depolyer module, which has dependencies of all other modules to be deployed here:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.parentname</groupId>
    <artifactId>product-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<groupId>com.parentname.product-services</groupId>
<artifactId>test-deployer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.parentname.product-services</groupId>
        <artifactId>product1-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <tasks>

                    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
                        <fileset dir="${project.basedir}">
                            <include name="**/jmeter.log" />
                        </fileset>
                    </delete>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>


            <configuration>

                <container>
                    <type>installed</type>
                    <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>

                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.42/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.42.zip</url>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>
                    </container>

                    <configuration>
                    <properties>
                    <cargo.servlet.port>4321</cargo.servlet.port>
                    <cargo.logging>medium</cargo.logging>
                    </properties>

                    </configuration>


                        <type>installed</type>
                        <deployables>


                            <deployable>
                                <groupId>com.parentname.product-services</groupId>
                                <artifactId>product1-webapp</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <properties>  
                                <context>product1-webapp</context>
                                </properties>
                            </deployable>

                        </deployables>

    <configfiles>
     <configfile>

     <file>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/context.xml</file>
     <todir>conf/Catalina/localhost/</todir>
     <tofile>context.xml</tofile>
   </configfile>
</configfiles>

                    </configuration>

                          <executions>



                          <execution>
                                <id>start-container</id>              
                                              <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>

                        <goal>start</goal>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>


        </plugin>
        <plugin> 
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>1.4</version> 
            <executions> 
                <execution> 
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id> 
                    <phase>integration-test</phase> 
                    <goals> 
                        <goal>jmeter</goal> 
                    </goals> 
                </execution> 
            </executions> 
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Solved my own problem, I had to move the <configfiles> tag to <continer><configuration></configuration></container>. Can't add this as a answer because I don't have enough reputation. Sigh!

Comment: so please post that answer yourself and accept it :)

Comment: Can't add this as a answer because I don't have enough reputation, so Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to. Sigh!

Answer (score 5):

For me, the solution was not to move `<configfiles>` under `<container><configuration>` as @Praveen said, but to move it under `<configuration><configuration>` as shown in the snippet below:

```
             <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                                <configuration>
                                    <configfiles>
                                        <configfile>
                                            <file>${basedir}/conf/my-context.xml</file>
                                            <todir>conf/</todir>
                                            <tofile>context.xml</tofile>
                                            <configfile>true</configfile>
                                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                                        </configfile>
                                    </configfiles>
                                </configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
```